# How to dynamically inject html to a react component and render the component inside it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a function component which receives an html content from an API. The html is injected to a component using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. How can I ask react to re run the cycle and render the react components received from the api response.

**Response from api**

```
<Carousel>
    <div>
        <img className='carousel-img' src="<image>" />
        <p className="legend">Legend 1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img className='carousel-img' src="<image>" />
        <p className="legend">Legend 2</p>
    </div>
</Carousel>
```

**Component**

```
const [previewContent, setPreviewContent] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:9001/getContent')
      .then(response => {
        setPreviewContent(response.data);
      })
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
      <div className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: previewContent}}></div>
      </div>      
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have imported the Carousel package in the component.
Once the Carousel code is injected to the div, how can it re run the cycle and render the `<Carousel>` component.

Comment: That seems like a terrible idea. Will it always be a carousel? You might be able to HTML parse the contents

Comment: Yes, the normal HTML contents are getting parsed and works fine.